# Query a REST API with Bearer token via UNIX bash script

Tags: bash, curl, centos, http-post

I managed to receive a token which looks reasonable and it is saved to the `token` variable.

I'm using this curl command to query the API:

```sh
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header "Authorization: Bearer $token" -d '*JSON format query*' '*Link*' | jq -r
```

In the API documentation provided by Swagger UI, inputting the *JSON format query* gives a Response Code 200 with a sensible Response Body. Basically the above code is just copied from the curl command generated by Swagger UI.

But I don't receive any output from my bash script besides:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time     Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   655    0     0  100   655      0   3266 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3275
[0][user@ip-xyz:/home/user/abc]
```

I tried playing around with the script (e.g. replacing $token with something unsensible) and still get the same output which makes me question if the token is even required and/or correct.

Comment: Is cURL command output correct without `jq` command ? If you want to remove percentages, add `--silent` option to cURL command. For `jq` command, add ` .` (space followed by a point) after `-r` option.

Comment: The question is a bit difficult to understand due to the formattting.

Comment: What data are you using in place of `'*JSON format query*' '*Link*`?

Comment: As expected the client flow token i received didn't authorize me to query the API. The code is correct. But my (active) client account had to be whitelisted for the API by the admins (at least that's what i understood) for the token to be accepted. Thanks for the attempts to help anyway!